# Simple way to optimize INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE SQL Server table includes columns with image data-type without Entity Framework in 3 steps (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, optimization, sqldatareader

I have an idea for optimize use of call SQL query command to get data from a table includes columns with `image` datatype using C# without Entity Framework in 3 steps:

**Step 0**: (default) Create a new table. This is my table `TBUsers`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBUsers]
(
    [STT] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HoTen] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [MaSo] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [MatKhau] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [KhoaLop] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [MaTheGui] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [PhanQuyen] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [ChoPhepHoatDong] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [NguoiThem] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [NgayThem] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [SoDuKhaDung] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [DangGui] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [TruyCapLanCuoi] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [ThoiGianGuiCuoi] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [HinhAnh] [IMAGE] NULL,
    [DonGia] [BIGINT] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TBUsers] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MaTheGui] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Step 1:** create a new class that corresponds to the table above and create 2 constructors, `Users`:

```
    public class Users
    {
        public Users()
        { }

        public Users(object sTT, object hoTen, object maSo, object matKhau, object khoaLop, object maTheGui, object phanQuyen, object choPhepHoatDong,
            object nguoiThem, object ngayThem, object soDuKhaDung, object dangGui, object truyCapLanCuoi, object thoiGianGuiCuoi, object hinhAnh,object donGia)
        {
            STT = sTT.ToString();
            HoTen = hoTen.ToString();
            MaSo = maSo.ToString();
            MatKhau = matKhau.ToString();
            KhoaLop = khoaLop.ToString();
            MaTheGui = maTheGui.ToString();
            PhanQuyen = phanQuyen.ToString();
            ChoPhepHoatDong = choPhepHoatDong.ToString();
            NguoiThem = nguoiThem.ToString();
            NgayThem = ngayThem.ToString();
            SoDuKhaDung = soDuKhaDung.ToString();
            DangGui = dangGui.ToString();
            TruyCapLanCuoi = truyCapLanCuoi.ToString();
            ThoiGianGuiCuoi = thoiGianGuiCuoi.ToString();

            HinhAnh = hinhAnh==System.DBNull.Value?null: (byte[])hinhAnh;
            DonGia = donGia.ToString();
            Color = (bool)choPhepHoatDong;
        }

        public string STT { get; set; }
        public string HoTen { get; set; }
        public string MaSo { get; set; }
        public string MatKhau { get; set; }
        public string KhoaLop { get; set; }
        public string MaTheGui { get; set; }
        public string PhanQuyen { get; set; }
        public string ChoPhepHoatDong { get; set; }
        public string NguoiThem { get; set; }
        public string NgayThem { get; set; }
        public string SoDuKhaDung { get; set; }
        public string DangGui { get; set; }
        public string TruyCapLanCuoi { get; set; }
        public string ThoiGianGuiCuoi { get; set; }
        public byte[] HinhAnh { get; set; }
        public string DonGia { get; set; }
        public bool Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Get `Users` from database with the `ParseUser` function:

```
    public static Users ParseUser(DataRow row)
    {
        var stt = row["STT"];
        var hoTen = row["HoTen"];
        var maSo = row["MaSo"];
        var matKhau = row["MatKhau"];
        var khoaLop = row["KhoaLop"];
        var maTheGui = row["MaTheGui"];
        var phanQuyen = row["PhanQuyen"];
        var choPhepHoatDong = row["ChoPhepHoatDong"];
        var nguoiThem = row["ChoPhepHoatDong"];
        var ngayThem = row["ChoPhepHoatDong"];
        var soDuKhaDung = row["SoDuKhaDung"];
        var dangGui = row["DangGui"];
        var truyCapLanCuoi = row["TruyCapLanCuoi"];
        var guiLanCuoi = row["ThoiGianGuiCuoi"];
        var hinhAnh = row["HinhAnh"] == System.DBNull.Value ? null : row["HinhAnh"];
        var donGia = row["DonGia"];

        return new Users(stt, hoTen, maSo, matKhau, khoaLop, maTheGui, phanQuyen, choPhepHoatDong, nguoiThem, ngayThem, soDuKhaDung, dangGui,
            truyCapLanCuoi, guiLanCuoi, hinhAnh, donGia);
    }
```

**Step 3:** Easily take an instance of Users class with `ParseUser` function:

```
Users user = Table.ParseUser(sqlUtility.GetDataTable($"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TBUsers] WHERE MaSo = 'xxx' AND ChoPhepHoatDong=1;").Rows[0]);
```

*Updating...*
Assume that I have many tables as below, and I want to insert into a specific table:

```
    public enum TableName
    {
        Users = 0,
        Registration,
        TheTamThoi
    }
```

Create a function to do that, `InsertWithImage`:

```
        public string InsertWithImage(TableName tableName, string[] fields, string[] values)
        {
            try
            {
                Connect();
                SqlCommand command;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter;
                string commandText = string.Empty;
                string table = string.Empty;
                switch (tableName)
                {
                    case TableName.Users:
                        table = "TBUsers";
                        break;
                    case TableName.Registration:
                        table = "TBRegistration";
                        break;
                    case TableName.TheTamThoi:
                        table = "TBTheTamThoi";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder($"INSERT INTO [dbo].[{table}](");

                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(i == fields.Length - 1 ? $"[{fields[i]}]) VALUES(" : $"[{fields[i]}],");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(i != values.Length - 1 ? $"@{fields[i]}, " : $"@{fields[i]})");
                }
                commandText = builder.ToString();
                command = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fields[i] == "HinhAnh")
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[i], string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[i]) ? (object)DBNull.Value : GetData(values[i])).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
                    else
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[i], values[i]);
                }

                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Dispose();
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

**Tips**

And assume that I want to get data from a table in database to insert into another:

Create a function to do that, `InsertWithImageFromDB`:

```
        public string InsertWithImageFromDB(TableName tableName, string[] fields, object[] values)
        {
            try
            {
                Connect();
                SqlCommand command;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter;
                string commandText = string.Empty;
                string table = string.Empty;
                switch (tableName)
                {
                    case TableName.Users:
                        table = "TBUsers";
                        break;
                    case TableName.Registration:
                        table = "TBRegistration";
                        break;
                    case TableName.TheTamThoi:
                        table = "TBTheTamThoi";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder($"INSERT INTO [DBBaiDoXe].[dbo].[{table}](");

                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(i == fields.Length - 1 ? $"[{fields[i]}]) VALUES(" : $"[{fields[i]}],");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(i != values.Length - 1 ? $"@{fields[i]}, " : $"@{fields[i]})");
                }
                commandText = builder.ToString();
                command = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[i], values[i]);
                }

                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Dispose();
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Done.

Is this a good solution?

I am continuing to write a simple solution to insert data into the `TBUsers` table with fields of image data-type. I will post the one in my later post.

Enjoy your code and give me some feedbacks.

Thank a lot !

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Also, in my opinion - using **Dapper** would pretty much do all of this (and a lot more) without having to re-write that code again and again .....

Comment: Can you fix that by writing some line of code, @marc_s?

Comment: Fix what?? Using `image` when you shouldn't ?  Just replace `image` with `varbinary(max)` - done! ....

Comment: Thanks for your useful info, @marc_s. I just want you to `Answer` to to anyone know that easier by the attention. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that I have many tables as below, and I want to insert into a specific table:

```
    public enum TableName
    {
        Users = 0,
        Registration,
        TheTamThoi
    }
```

Create a function to do that, `InsertWithImage`:

```
        public string InsertWithImage(TableName tableName, string[] fields, string[] values)
        {
            try
            {
                Connect();
                SqlCommand command;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter;
                string commandText = string.Empty;
                string table = string.Empty;
                switch (tableName)
                {
                    case TableName.Users:
                        table = "TBUsers";
                        break;
                    case TableName.Registration:
                        table = "TBRegistration";
                        break;
                    case TableName.TheTamThoi:
                        table = "TBTheTamThoi";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder($"INSERT INTO [dbo].[{table}](");

                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(i == fields.Length - 1 ? $"[{fields[i]}]) VALUES(" : $"[{fields[i]}],");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    builder.Append(i != values.Length - 1 ? $"@{fields[i]}, " : $"@{fields[i]})");
                }
                commandText = builder.ToString();
                command = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fields[i] == "HinhAnh")
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[i], string.IsNullOrEmpty(values[i]) ? (object)DBNull.Value : GetData(values[i])).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
                    else
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(fields[i], values[i]);
                }

                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Dispose();
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return string.Empty;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.
Just solve for you.